# White boxes in select element using Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with my select boxes that I styled in CSS. When hovering over in Chrome white boxes appear. Everything is fine in Safari. Any clues?
I have added my css and html, and also pictures of the problem. The first one is Safari, and the second one is Chrome

```css
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 10;
 left 50%;
 width: 190px;
 height: 2em;
 line-height: 2;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 overflow:scroll ;
 border-radius: .35em;
 margin-bottom: 5px;

}
.dropdown select {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background-image: none; /* remove the value that chrome dose not use */
    background-color: #E9B6B0; /* set the value it does */
    border-radius: 4px;     /* make it look kinda like the background image */
    border: 1px solid #888;
 outline: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 border: 0 !important;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
 color: black;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 15px;

}

.dropdown::after {
 content: '\25BE';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0 1em;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown:hover::after {
 color: white;
}
.dropdown::after {
 -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
 -o-transition: .25s all ease;
 transition: .25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <select id="genre" onchange="filterConcerts()" value="default">
  <option value="default">Sjanger</option>
</div>
```

[image: Boxes in Safari]

[image: Boxes in Chrome]

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions running in Chrome? I've seen stuff like that injected by extensions. Try viewing it in an incognito window without extensions installed. Also, try inspecting that little spot with the Dev Tools for clues.

Comment: I don't see any white boxes. Can you inspect that part of the drodpown? A pseudo-selector maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change overflow:scroll; to overflow: auto; in your .dropdown class

```css
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 10;
 left 50%;
 width: 190px;
 height: 2em;
 line-height: 2;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 overflow:auto ;
 border-radius: .35em;
 margin-bottom: 5px;

}
.dropdown select {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background-image: none; /* remove the value that chrome dose not use */
    background-color: #E9B6B0; /* set the value it does */
    border-radius: 4px;     /* make it look kinda like the background image */
    border: 1px solid #888;
 outline: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 border: 0 !important;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
 color: black;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 15px;

}

.dropdown::after {
 content: '\25BE';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0 1em;
 background: #E9B6B0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown:hover::after {
 color: white;
}
.dropdown::after {
 -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
 -o-transition: .25s all ease;
 transition: .25s all ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <select id="genre" onchange="filterConcerts()" value="default">
  <option value="default">Sjanger</option>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)